# I am new to the React and I don't know why this doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

```
render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello, world!</p>
      <p>Hello, React!</p>
    );
}
```

If

tag is only one, it works, but in this case, it doesn't work. What's the problem?
Thank you for your considering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cover two lines using Div tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice against wrapping it with div because of their abstraction in DOM Tree. You need to wrap you components into a fragment to ensure single parent rule:

e.g.

```
render() {
    return (
     <React.Fragment>
      <p>Hello, world!</p>
      <p>Hello, React!</p> 
     </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

You can also you <> instead of Fragments i.e.

```
  render() {
        return (
         <>
          <p>Hello, world!</p>
          <p>Hello, React!</p> 
         </>
        );
    }
```